# Issues using jdk.incubator.vector in a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to figure out how to use the `jdk.incubator.vector` inside my Maven Project, but it always return these errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import jdk.incubator cannot be resolved
    The import jdk.incubator cannot be resolved
    VectorSpecies cannot be resolved to a type
    FloatVector cannot be resolved to a variable
    VectorSpecies cannot be resolved to a type
    DoubleVector cannot be resolved to a type
    DoubleVector cannot be resolved
    VectorSpecies cannot be resolved to a type
    .....
```

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Use JDK 17, instead of the default one (JDK 1.5) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                        <arg>jdk.incubator.vector</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Testing Settings -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <org.vanilladb.core.config.file>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/org/vanilladb/core/vanilladb.properties</org.vanilladb.core.config.file>
                        <java.util.logging.config.file>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/java/util/logging/logging.properties</java.util.logging.config.file>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <argLine>--add-modules</argLine>
                    <argLine>jdk.incubator.vector</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>org/vanilladb/core/FullTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
....
```

I would then compile the code into a runnable jar file, and run it.
And my run argument would look like the following:

```
java -jar --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dorg.vanilladb.bench.config.file=vanillabench.properties -Dorg.vanilladb.core.config.file=vanilladb.properties server.jar baseline_DB
```

I'm very new to Maven, can someone kindly help to resolve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: BTW: I would suggest to upgrade your surefire plugin version as well as the maven-compiler-plugin version to most recent versions and also use JDK21 ...Also use most recent version of Maven...

Comment: The step to get a runnable jar you have to use maven-shade-plugin but I would say that's the next step. First get it compiled etc.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for surefire/failsafe/compiler plugin:

Using the [following versions of maven plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/):

- maven-compiler-plugin version 3.11.0
- maven-surefire-plugin version 3.1.2
- maven-failsafe-plugin version 3.1.2

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
  ..
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>jdk.incubator.vector</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

An example with Vector API (running on JDK 21 ea build):

```
package com.soebes.jdk21.incubator;

import jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector;
import jdk.incubator.vector.VectorSpecies;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class VectorTest {

  static final VectorSpecies<Float> SPECIES = FloatVector.SPECIES_256;

  void vectorComputation(float[] a, float[] b, float[] c) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += SPECIES.length()) {
      var m = SPECIES.indexInRange(i, a.length);
      // FloatVector va, vb, vc;
      var va = FloatVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a, i, m);
      var vb = FloatVector.fromArray(SPECIES, b, i, m);
      var vc = va.mul(va).
          add(vb.mul(vb)).
          neg();
      vc.intoArray(c, i, m);
    }
  }

  @Test
  void name() {
    float[] a = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
    float[] b = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
    float[] c = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};

    vectorComputation(a, b, c);
  }
}
```

You can find a full working example here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk21 and in that class: https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk21/blob/main/src/test/java/com/soebes/jdk21/incubator/VectorTest.java
But you have to install most recent JDK 21 ea build.